# Change request input values from empty string to null in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, httprequest, jquery-select2

In my controller I receive an `Illuminate\Http\Request` Request that contains some data with values equal to an empty string:

```
dd($request->input())

//output
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "K43q88mR5zQRqVPAuYX5IWtQ1khQ24JTsuxl8mz4"
  "param1" => "1"
  "param2" => "2"
  "param3" => ""
  "param4" => ""
]
```

(*basically that happens when the user had made no selections in the create form BUT due to frontend restrictions [see here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/841), **I am not able to change the form of the Request** so that to exclude the empty string values from being sent to the server*)

The request input data is used to attach a relationships to models. For example:

```
$book->authors()->attach($request->input('param1'));
```

The problem is that when the input value is equal to the empty string `""` the above line  throws a `QueryException`, since it tries to add a foreign key equal to `""` to the pivot table.

On the other hand, I noticed that if the value is `null` instead of `""`, the `attach()` method is not executed and, thus, does not throws an Exception, neither updates the database, which is exactly the behavior I want, when the user made no selection in the input form.

My question is **how can I change the request values from `""` to `null`?** My first thought was to make a helper function that iterates over the request input array and replace "" with null and use it in the controller BUT it does not seems like a good idea for me, because this would not prevent possible unwanted validation errors, when using Form Request Validation.

Any ideas please ???

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## NOTE: Laravel 5.4 now ships with this feature

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization

For versions > 5.4 see answer below or just copy the official middlewares.

---

> [HTTP middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application.](https://laravel.com/docs/middleware)

Make a middleware and assign it to the routes or controller's methods you want it to take place.

Example:

```php
class SanitizeMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach ($request->input() as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                $request->request->set($key, null);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```php
Route::post('/users', function (Request $request) {

    dd($request->input());

})->middleware(SanitizeMiddleware::class);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however anyone using it may want to explicity check for string '0' which is perfectly valid..

`if ($value !== '0' && empty($value)) {`

Answer (score 3):

This being said you can solve your problem as follows:
Comment out or put this in middleware in the
`App\Http\Kernel.php` file.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just check before you add an item to your pivot table?

```
if(!empty($request->input('paramX'))){
    $book->authors()->attach($request->input('paramX'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I am acctualy using `if ($request->input('paramX') != "")` for every single input parameter. What I am asking is for a more "global" without the need to include the if statement everytime for every single request input parameter.